# How to start debugger with an entry_point script

Tags: python

I have a package installed in development mode with `pip install -e ./mylocalpkg`.

This package defines an `entry_points.console_script`

```
setup(
    name='mylocalpkg',
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myscript = mylocalpkg.scriptfile:main'
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

This script can be called with either way

```
$ python -m mylocalpkg.scriptfile
$ myscript
```

However, I cannot debug this script:

```
$ python -m pdb mylocalpkg.scriptfile
Error: mylocalpkg.scriptfile does not exist
$ python -m pdb myscript
Error: myscript does not exist
```

How can I start a debugging session with `pdb` while calling entry_point scripts ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `pdb` module must be called with the name of a Python script, not a module. So you somehow need to give it a script to run.

If you're on Linux/Unix/Mac, you're in luck, because `myscript` is actually a Python script, so you can use one of these options:

```
python -m pdb `which myscript`
# or
python -m pdb $(which myscript)
```

These find the location of `myscript` and pass it to the `pdb` module. You could also specify the location of `myscript` directly, if you happen to know that.

If you're on Windows, you'll need to create a script that loads your entry_point, and then debug that. Here's a short script that could do the job:

```
# run_myscript.py
import pkg_resources
myscript = pkg_resources.load_entry_point('mylocalpkg', 'console_scripts', 'myscript')
myscript()
```

Then you can debug via this command:

```
python -m pdb run_myscript.py
```

Or, on any platform, you can use this ugly one-liner:

```
python -c "import pdb, pkg_resources; pdb.run('pkg_resources.load_entry_point(\'mylocalpkg\', \'console_scripts\', \'myscript\')()')"
```

Also, in this particular case, where you want to debug a module that can be loaded via `python -m mylocalpkg.scriptfile`, you can use a simpler one-liner:

```
python -c "import pdb; pdb.run('import mylocalpkg.scriptfile')"
```

Comment: I'm on Windows but your answer applies as well, I tried with a relative path and it works. Your answer got me thinking that python is capable of finding the location of a module using the `__path__` attribute so it could be possible for pdb to locate a module file directly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Glad it helped. I've also added some Windows options, not sure if these match what you did.

Comment: Thanks, that one liner was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Just realized that in your case you could also shorten it to `python -c "import pdb; pdb.run('import mylocalpkg.scriptfile')"`

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that causes problems here is not where the source files are installed, but syntax used for the `import` statements.

## Python 2 only:

```
import submodule2
```

## Python 2 and 3:

```
from . import submodule2
```

If one sticks to the latter convention, it "just works".

Lastly, highly recommend `pudb` for on-target debugging. No setup. just install and go. (Although, it's easier to apt-install python3-pudb than try get it installed in the appropriate/same venv)

Sample command line for a locally installed wheel with a command line entry pointing to this file, and shows args for the script:

```
pudb3 /opt/venv/xxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xxx/create_xxx.py  arg1 --database param1 --host hostbparam.com -
```