# Using cProfile on application with entry point

Tags: python, cprofile

I know cProfile can be used like this

```
python -m cProfile script.py
```

But suppose I have a packaged application (pip-installable) with an `entry_point` defined in setup.py, such that I can call the application from the terminal, without explicitly using any .py file. How can I use cProfile in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45930920/11580689):

```
python -m cProfile $(which application)
```

Comment: `$(which application)` is simply your entry point script (with path).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, I didn't know that's what I had to call with cProfile.

Comment: You don't. If you know the path you just put it as you mentioned in your question. What `$(...)` does is invoking `which` that returns full path of `application` (if on PATH).

Answer (score 0):

What if someone is using click for CLI ?
It seems not to be working for me.

Update:
Actually cProfile requires **main**, and adding standard

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    cli()
```

to mymodule/cli.py program, solved the issue.